# What's the difference between the app based on backbone.js/ember.js and the one based on Phonegap/Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, cordova, backbone.js, sencha-touch

As mobile web app gets more and more prevailing, a lot of tools become available for developing mobile web app. In my opinion(I don't know if it's correct), there are two ways to develop mobile web app.

One way is to use some javascript framework such as backbone.js and ember.js combined with some other libraries such as Zepto and iScroll to do this. The other way is to use some integerated toolkit such as PhoneGap and Sencha Touch to write the whole thing. What I want to know is what's the difference between these two ways? How should I choose between these two ways?

Comment: the options you provide are not mutually exclusive. phonegap is a web application wrapper for creating native mobile applications. it can be used with ember, backbone, sencha touch, etc.

Comment: @filmaj Ok. So what's the differnce between sencha touch and ember/backbone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640135/difference-between-sencha-and-phonegap/12640341#12640341  this clears off your confusion bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phonegap is a wrapper framework which helps html/javascript app to run in a native container and give a medium to execute a native code whereever required. Phonegap is not integrated with Sencha Touch, you can use it with any client-size javascript frameworks like backbonejs, amberjs, jquery, jquery mobile, etc. Application built using Phonegap comes under hybrid application category.

Please check some of this preps to get more info:

http://www.slideshare.net/macdonst/building-native-mobile-applications-with-phonegap
http://www.slideshare.net/kurotanshi/jsdctw-introduction-to-phonegap

Comment: Thanks. So what is the difference between apps based on Sencha Touch and Backbone/ember? Does Sencha Touch just have some additional mobile UI modules compared to backbone/ember?

Comment: in a way sencha touch is a all in one application framework which includes UI and MVP framework to manage and control the application. Backbone/Amber on the other hand is utility library which gives only application management stuff. Sentch Touch only works on webkit due to UI dependency, however backbone/amber can run on any browser as they do not include any UI dependencies.

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7287968/805003)  which greatly clarifies the difference between Backbone.js and Sencha Touch.